# callback function executes before the finished request.on function

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, callback, node-modules

I made a `npm module` for my personal use to download file
using `request` and displaying the progress bar using `progress`

https://github.com/MaxySpark/maxyspark-download

but when I test it the callback function executes first, it should execute after finished the download.

my test file

```
const maxDonwload = require('maxyspark-download');

var filename = "prog.gif";
var url = "http://skillprogramming.com/images/pictuers/how_many_of_you_get_the_same_feeling.gif";
function endFunc() {
    console.log("download completed : "+filename);
}
maxDonwload.download(url,filename,endFunc());
```

Here is the output

```
download completed : prog.gif
File Size : 0.50 MB

  downloading [====================] 100% 0.0s
HERE HERE
```

I added a the line `console.log("HERE HRERE");` to node-modules index.js file  in

```
req.on('end' function() {
    console.log("HERE HRERE");
    callback;
}
```

[image]

**console.log("HERE HRERE"); execute after the download complete but callback does not**.

Comment: You calling your endfunc straight away, remove the `()`,  `maxDonwload.download(url,filename,endFunc);`

Comment: did not worked. output-
`File Size : 0.50 MB

  downloading [====================] 100% 0.0s
HERE HERE`

Comment: the error may be here
can you please check this?

[index.js- GitHub](https://github.com/MaxySpark/maxyspark-download/blob/master/index.js)

Comment: Indeed  `callback;` will do nothing...  This is were we want our `()`...  `callback();`

Comment: oh thanx @Keith. I understand now...`callback()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the function, instead you should pass it as argument without the ():

```
maxDonwload.download(url,filename,endFunc);
```

Comment: did not worked. output-
`File Size : 0.50 MB

  downloading [====================] 100% 0.0s
HERE HERE`

Comment: the error may be here
can you please check this?

[index.js- GitHub](https://github.com/MaxySpark/maxyspark-download/blob/master/index.js)

Comment: On my computer it's working, saves the file. It only doest log the time that took to download. It's error in the library for me.

Comment: thanx! there were two errors one you mentioned and another one is in `index.js` file in node module, i wrote `callback` it should be `callback()` as said by @Keith

Answer (score 1):

You are calling endFunc() instead of passing the function itself as a parameter.

This should fix it:

```
maxDonwload.download(url,filename,endFunc);
```

Comment: did not worked. output-
`File Size : 0.50 MB

  downloading [====================] 100% 0.0s
HERE HERE`

Comment: the error may be here
can you please check this?

[index.js- GitHub](https://github.com/MaxySpark/maxyspark-download/blob/master/index.js)